# Jquery Promt check if in jPrompt

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok hello guys here is my problem i was try to create a jPrompt   but i can't understand how can i make a simple if ckeck. I find the code [here](http://runnable.com/UfNMPnKMU1ZgAACQ/how-to-create-custom-jquery-alert-confirm-and-prompt-dialogs) and i crate it again.Now i want to do something simple, the user click the button and must enter a code for example number 123, and i must check if the number is 123(true) then run an sql query else run this function again unless the user click cancel button and not ok.

I need a good example to learn how t use  if statement with Jquery, any simple idea beginner in (jQuery) sorry!!!.

This is what i have try

```
$("#prompt_button").click( function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                /*
                    jPrompt is function which will show custom promt window.
                    It has three argument.
                    First argument is label text.
                    Second is the predefined value for promt.
                    Third is promt heading.
                    and has callback function which will perform exatra 
                    code like what user enter.
                */
                jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog',  function(r)
                {
                    if(r!=123){jPrompt('Enter the right code plese: ');}
                    else jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');


                });
            });
```

Comment: Your "else" appears to be missing "{}" if(r!=123){jPrompt('Enter the right code plese: ');}
else {jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results')};

Comment: Yes i see that sorry but  i try only one code and if is not 123 calling jPrompt('Enter the right code please: '); but when i try a second rong code for example 234 the prompt box close.I want until the use fill the code 123 or click cancel button the prompt box show again and again

Comment: The first try the function take the first code, but if is false the second time can't take the second code there is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys the answer it was easy to find after 2-3 hours i was searching, and (now i will hit my head to the monitor in front of me), here is the code

```
    $("#prompt_button").click( function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                /*
                    jPrompt is function which will show custom promt window.
                    It has three argument.
                    First argument is label text.
                    Second is the predefined value for promt.
                    Third is promt heading.
                    and has callback function which will perform exatra 
                    code like what user enter.
                */
                jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r)
                {
                    if( r!=123 ) {$("#prompt_button").click();}
                    else{window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"}

                });
            });
```

It's nice to loose 2-3 hours for something like that, it was simple just call, with the right way, the function (Programming for Dummies( <-This is for Me ). Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem. Can you supply any code?

> I need a good example to learn how t use if statement with Jquery, any
>   simple idea beginner in (jQuery) sorry!!!.

An "if" statement is fundamental to any client/server language.(Maybe different syntax in some)

```
var i = 123;
$('.selector').click(function()
{
 if(i == 123)
   {
    alert("Value is " + i);
   }
});
```

Pretty basic click event with an "if" statement. It maybe a good idea to hit a book store or pluralsight.

//Edits

Please remember when creating the later part of an "if / else" statement it needs to be wrapped in curly braces "{}"

Regards,

Comment: I add some of the code i have try so far but with this i try only one code and if is not 123 calling jPrompt('Enter the right code please: '); but when i try a second rong code for example 234 the prompt box close.I want until the use fill the code 123 or  click cancel button the prompt box show again and again.